# ASP.net Google Maps

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

I'm trying to add a google map into a div on a ASP .Net child page (it has a masterpage). The map information seems to get loaded from google - but I can't see anything. When I hit F12 in chrome I can see my div has been filled with lots of other divs and data about the map.

Any ideas why I the map is invisible?

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Contact.aspx.cs" Inherits="CentralWebsite.Contact" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 317px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            var myOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);
            alert("alert " + document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td class="style1">
                <h1>Telephone: 01709</h1>
                <h1>Address</h1>
                <h3></h3>
                <h3>Rotherham</h3>
                <h3>South Yorkshire</h3>
                <h3>S60 1PP</h3>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%">
                    map should go here
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</asp:Content>
```

I am calling the initialize function by adding it as the onload attribute of the master page body as follows:

```
 public partial class Contact : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl myBody = (HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("myBody");
            myBody.Attributes.Add("onload", "initialize()");
        }
    }
```

Many thanks

Rob.

Comment: You have to call the javascript method initialize() on the starting page. Then will works!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain - I am calling the initialize function from the page_load of the child page. I know that initialize is being called because the Alert dialog displayed

Answer (score 1):

In Master page, You should set id "myBody" and runat "server" in  tag.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you not call the `initialize()` anywhere !

Call it on page load, or on dom ready, or just call it after the div of the map

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%">map should go here</div>
<script>initialize();</script>
```

or even better at the close of the table that contains the div map

```
</table>
    <script>initialize();</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First it looks like your using version 2 of the api which has your key..you do not need this for version 3. Second, I use JQuery to call the initialize instead of adding attributes in code-behind, just seems buggy and I struggled with it and getting it to work awhile back.

Try like this (I have local reference to JQuery specified, adjust if necessary)

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        initialize();
    });


    function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
        alert("alert " + document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    }
</script>
```

Also, in css explicitly set height/width for the map_canvas:

```
#map_canvas
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 265px;
    border:1px solid #C3C8BD;
    border-radius:5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Web Forms**, in order to get a *visible* map, I have always had to **both** call `initialize()` **and** explicitly set the width and height of the `map_canvas` div to number of pixels. You can verify that percentages cause the map div height to equal 0 px by examining the div using F12 developer tools or Firebug.

This code shows a map div that resizes as the browser resizes. Note the javascript is put into files that are referenced by the `"~/bundles/gmaps"`.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="testme.aspx.cs" Inherits="drawingTools.testme" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=drawing"></script>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        <%: System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/gmaps") %>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', myPageLoad);
        </script>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">        
        <div id="map_canvas" class="map_canvas" >
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In the *aspx* code `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', pageLoad);`
 serves to invoke the `myPageLoad` function when the window has loaded.  Or use the *JQuery* `$(document).ready` function to wait for the document to be ready for google maps initialization.

```
function myPageLoad() {
    resize();  
    initialize(); // your google.map initializer
}
```

The `resize()` function used for resizable maps. You can tweak this according to requirements. The purpose is to set the dimensions of the `map_canvas` div to 100%.

```
function resize() {
  var main = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
  main.style.height = (getWindowHeight()) + "px";
  main.style.width = (getWindowWidth()) + "px";
}
onresize = function () { resize(); };
```

The javascript functions, `getWindowHeight()` and `getWindowWidth()` can be obtained from many sources or you can write your own.

As an editorial aside, using google maps on aspx pages presents challenges. E.g. a postback from a button control will invoke the myPageLoad function when not desired with bad results, unless the postback is disabled.